# Tunneling using Plink to localhost on Windows

Tags: ssh, putty, ssh-tunnel, plink

Currently im using following command (in `cmd`) to tunnel using PuTTY, and it's working fine:

```
putty.exe mylinuxuser@10.24.0.5 -P 22 -L 10.24.0.200:2022:localhost:22
```

- 10.24.0.5 = my application server (CentOS 7)
- 10.24.0.200 = my workstation (Windows 10)

I'm running the above command on my workstation (10.24.0.200) and it's working fine. I'm able to connect to
10.24.0.200 port 2022 from my PC.

The question is: what is the equivalent command for `plink.exe` for tunneling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plink has the very same [command-line syntax](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter7.html#plink-usage) as PuTTY:

```
plink.exe mylinuxuser@10.24.0.5 -P 22 -L 10.24.0.200:2022:localhost:22
```